# Laravel Vite - Configuration does not exist

Tags: laravel, vite

I tried to create Laravel project with Vite and followed Laravel documentation. But the problem occurred when I tried to access the resource and it says **Configuration "resources/js/app.js" does not exist.**.

This is `vite.config.js` file:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel([
            'resources/css/app.css',
            'resources/js/app.js',
        ]),
        vue(),
    ],
});
```

And this is my blade file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Test</title>

    {{-- @vite('resources/css/app.css') --}}
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>

    @vite('resources/js/app.js')
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Error message]

[image: Resources directory]

Anyone know the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this in vite.config.js.

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

And then make sure that you run `npm run build` in your terminal.

Comment: Hmm, isnt it for production and I should change the `@vite('resources/js/app.js')` on blade file? It still has same output

Comment: I have found the problem, it was due to conflict between offical vite and 3rd party vite (`innocenzi/laravel-vite`). Removing one of them solving the issue.

src: https://github.com/laravel/vite-plugin/issues/65

Answer (score 0):

use @vite('default') in you blade file not : @vite('resources/js/app.js')  more info go to :
https://laravel-vite.dev/guide/extra-topics/multiple-configurations.html#configuring-the-laravel-package

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).